# Grunt Preprocessor Not Workgin

Tags: html, build, gruntjs

I'm working on an HTML 5 app that I'm building with Grunt. I am trying to use the [grunt-preprocess](https://github.com/jsoverson/grunt-preprocess/) task on my HTML. In attempt to just see if it works, I have the preprocess task setup as follows:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    return {
        dev: {
            cwd: 'build/temp',          
            src: [
                '**/*.css',
                '**/*.js',
                'index.html',
                'app/**/*.html'
            ],
            options: {
                inline : true,
                context: {
                    ENV: 'dev'
                }
            }
        }
    };
};
```

I have a basic index.html file that looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- @exclude -->
    <header>You're on dev!</header>
    <!-- @endexclude -->

    Welcome    
  </body>
</html>
```

I've added the exclude directive just to see if its running through the preprocessor. I know that grunt is running the preprocess task. I'm basing this on the fact that when I run `grunt --verbose`, I see the following at the end:

```
Running "preprocess:dev" (preprocess) task
Verifying property preprocess.dev exists in config...OK
Files: css/animations.css, css/app.css, css/application.css,...

Verifying property preprocess exists in config...OK
Options: inline, context={"ENV":"dev"}
Reading css/animations.css...ERROR
Warning: Unable to read "css/animations.css" file (Error code: ENOENT). Use --force to continue.
```

I can't make sense of this error. The error says css/animations.css can't be found. Yet, it shows it in the Files list previously. I've also confirmed its on the file system.

Can somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `expand: true` when using `cwd`.

See http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically for more info

Your task would become:

```
dev: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'build/temp',          
        src: [
            '**/*.css',
            '**/*.js',
            'index.html',
            'app/**/*.html'
        ],
        options: {
            inline : true,
            context: {
                ENV: 'dev'
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I added expand:true. While the task gets beyond that step, I still have `<!-- @exclude -->
    <header>You're on dev!</header>
    <!-- @endexclude -->` in my code. It's not actually processing. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I haven't had any experience with preprocess myself, just saw the `expand:true` bit. If I have a bit of time later I will take a look and see if I can find anything.

Comment: Thank you. I would sincerely appreciate your insights. I'm still trying to figure out it. Haven't had any luck yet. I'll post a response here if I figure it out.

Comment: Well, I did not get it to work. I decided to use the `grunt-text-replace` plugin instead and things are working now. Thank you for trying.